# How to decrypt an encrypted string with unknown decryption

Tags: string, encryption

I have this String which I wish to decrypt

```
x7jxBpEygx2DJXppdyBeso9bUKs3AFRYPd4V93TP16ZmP12kaA2qyYoVPCdyKQAlK2F41TqQR2kX
q0AVeXPPTVJNN/J4BmzIHaoS3xJKNNeSKM6DXu0lkWA+MG5T9bGRuoNQcb7bJp0dz22Xz3wS9KfF
MY7mOKNBQIriYCwjU9b23cL/xIC0Ix0NESNcKchCcKUHm/QxD2pmeQ5pS9xda4BW2t0+E+yUtwxa
ae9lo+dniSPT/hj6cO9UkvKOqzXpktKwW0ljlJcCRp5sJ5p1dQedEAcKb2CcnNotjdtzwAzCzMXI
4qV3OXRZ3es3ql3n4e0q7wYKs1Huu05Z5cg3Skr5+sjqx27D1X+bQdoQIWOt6VsX52oll6JtzSQx
XXfja6fYYArX3rlXqvbHD8ht3vWO5kSTbXe58/pZ6uvvcz2q7OI483c8YphXxb88iCWRK/IE7Z7h
ROueTT2nbU7jJRGF6nZS2C9r/wWRT28a8vnINMzEzeV0MAPfW1ZBs/xEMH5VatNyjti1G58wvU+F
ksfifxdJ41XjKhJmV/kUIlmQtKQtJsC75rCTDtetVIXBzKlHy5XvqKkL5ZTJwoirwMmWXX7+6O2w
UQIOri6ZP4yTwGE/2BJueDFp98Oy/2cdWUNYYIACM+xIHw/wtyNTn/hYOwxpG+LcbuvdVUW2Ihwe
b7oosEif3idUSEolBf8tBwFvfW4XYVkvr3LB02JvBoU0xGCykNNsFDURKa9U6AlX1a/4POPX98t5
ZkMlw52vlxhCQV3iGb9Egrpm5ymKUdLtYW7KUDI0JnooIEy3a8stnTfVwpxNodk9jvjCIi4CwtL0
JjFtjUeXHXebVo/o8jiB7TO5+cwjJktcArbRpPKS/glAWKBhzpTxJXijUcwn8SF6vHeMNosAbOvG
7d86pwPMUS+0ycOplqAl7vgKkf9SzEtV0MTztb//L6jfTVRpkPwbYZuzOU2sg7YszRsl+Pw++E5q
HJ6JzcfxJWBvSPv5eL6qH1JBgRo+StuqTj0QwH2L81GKY5ilXL9oDHpiIpQ/p6FeyWEK9yG9Vi0+
c/P0InNgYbbAQ8WM0cqWKldWPCpjkg4MXcwg9RVlSIjCWsG3Pr+amZN6DoGkNDUxCRvmxKjjvXZK
9r9dulv2GRhw
```

but I do not know the method used to encrypt this string.
Is there any method on how to find out what encryption is used and to decrypt this string?

Comment: That is a base64 encoded and contains some binary data. But I have no idea how this data are crypted.

Comment: I cannot help thinking that if it where that easy to decrypt, then the encryption would not be worth its salt (no pun intended).

Comment: What for?Do you have the key?

Comment: I don't have the key, is a key needed here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have a private key. You can't decrypt. If you don't have an encryption method and don't have a key. You super can't decrypt.

There's no method to figure out what encryption was used. And even if you did know unless it was md5 (I can tell by looking it isn't) or something else super easy (not likely) then there's no perfect method for breaking into it and most of those methods involve a super computer and lots and lots of time.